# Post to slack returns 400 because JSON is in hashtable format

Tags: powershell, slack-api

I am writing a powershell script to post a message to slack :

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$newrelicAppName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$releasenumber,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$RequestedBy,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$SourceVersion
)

$uriSlack = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/MYDATA"

$jsonBase = @{}
$blocksList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$fieldsList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Null = $fieldsList.Add(@{"type"="mrkdwn";"text"="*Release Number* $releasenumber";})
$Null = $fieldsList.Add(@{"type"="mrkdwn";"text"="*Requested By* $RequestedBy";})
$Null = $fieldsList.Add(@{"type"="mrkdwn";"text"="*Source Version* $SourceVersion";})

$textData = @{"type"="plain_text";"text"="Release completed for $($newrelicAppName)";}
$dividerData = @{"type"="divider";}

$Null = $blocksList.Add(@{"type"="header"; "text"=$textData})
$Null = $blocksList.Add(@{"type"="divider"})
$Null = $blocksList.Add(@{"type"="section"; "fields"=$fieldsList;})

$blocksList | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4

$Null = $jsonBase.Add("blocks",$blocksList)

write-output $jsonBase.GetType()

try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uriSlack -Method Post -body $jsonBase -ContentType 'application/json' | Out-Null
} catch {
    Write-Output $_
    Write-Error "Update to Slack went wrong..."
}
```

This currently returns a 400 message :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
```

And if I looks at the GetType() output, I can see that the $jsonBase is actually still a HashTable:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                   
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

I thought that adding the -Depth 4 to the conversion would fix this, but apparently not!
If I copy the output of $jsonBase into postman and post the plain text, it works. So I know it is something to do with the generated JSON, and not the format of the message.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the conversion of the hashtable to JSON besides `$blocklist`, but it's only output to the console. Then, you only specify the `$jsonbase`.

Comment: Does it work if you do `-body ($jsonBase |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4)` instead?

Comment: Actually, that works! Not sure why, but i'll take it! Thanks bud.

Comment: I've edited the code to reflect the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @evolmonster Please never do that, it makes your question less valuable to others in the future. I've posted an answer below, which I encourage you to accept - but you're of course also free to post your own answer below if you've found a better solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly convert the body payload to JSON by doing:

```
Invoke-RestMethod ... -Body ($jsonBase |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4)
```